# How to restrict occurrence of a complex type in sequence in xsd?

Tags: xsd

I want to have xsd for following exemplary xml:

```
<Action name="noname">
<choices>
<choice attrib1="hi" attrib2="hello" attrib3="test" />
<choice attrib1="hi1" attrib2="hello1" attrib3="test1" />
<choice attrib1="hi2" attrib2="hello2" attrib3="test3" />
<choice attrib1="hi" />
</choices>
</Action>
```

As you can see above. I want to have atleast one "choice" without "attrib2" and "attrib3". how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand completely, but you could declare the attribute attrib1 as required, and the choice element with minOccurs="1". Like so:

```
<xs:element name="choices">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="choice" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="attrib1" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="attrib2" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="attrib3" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

However this might restrict you more than you need to. Is attrib1 going to be required for all choice elements?